# FileBasedSource not able to understand a glob corresponding to several specific files in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: java, scala, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I need to process customed binary files stored in Google Cloud Storage in a Dataflow job.

To do that, I wrote a custom [FileBasedSource](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/FileBasedSource). As the documentation states, it's *backed by a file pattern defined as a Java glob, a single file, or a offset range for a single file*.

In my case, I need to use a Java glob with several specific filenames, like this `/path/{file1,file1,file3}`. When I test it on the local filesystem it works fine, but if I use it with Google Cloud Storage (`gs://bucket/{file1,file2,file3}`) it's not able to find any file and I get the following stacktrace :

```
java.io.IOException: Error executing batch GCS request
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.GcsUtil.executeBatches(GcsUtil.java:603)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.GcsUtil.getObjects(GcsUtil.java:342)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsFileSystem.matchNonGlobs(GcsFileSystem.java:217)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.gcp.storage.GcsFileSystem.match(GcsFileSystem.java:86)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileSystems.match(FileSystems.java:111)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileBasedSource.getEstimatedSizeBytes(FileBasedSource.java:207)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.internal.CustomSources.serializeToCloudSource(CustomSources.java:78)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.ReadTranslator.translateReadHelper(ReadTranslator.java:53)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.ReadTranslator.translate(ReadTranslator.java:40)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.ReadTranslator.translate(ReadTranslator.java:37)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowPipelineTranslator$Translator.visitPrimitiveTransform(DataflowPipelineTranslator.java:439)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:602)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:594)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.access$500(TransformHierarchy.java:276)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:210)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.traverseTopologically(Pipeline.java:440)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowPipelineTranslator$Translator.translate(DataflowPipelineTranslator.java:383)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowPipelineTranslator.translate(DataflowPipelineTranslator.java:173)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.run(DataflowRunner.java:556)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.run(DataflowRunner.java:167)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:297)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:283)
        at com.travelaudience.data.job.rtbtobigquery.Main$.main(Main.scala:74)
        at com.travelaudience.data.job.rtbtobigquery.Main.main(Main.scala)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 400 Bad Request
        at org.apache.beam.sdks.java.extensions.google.cloud.platform.core.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:500)
        at org.apache.beam.sdks.java.extensions.google.cloud.platform.core.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:479)
        at org.apache.beam.sdks.java.extensions.google.cloud.platform.core.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:76)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.GcsUtil.executeBatches(GcsUtil.java:595)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 400 Bad Request
        at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1070)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.batch.BatchRequest.execute(BatchRequest.java:241)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.GcsUtil$3.call(GcsUtil.java:588)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.GcsUtil$3.call(GcsUtil.java:586)
        at org.apache.beam.sdks.java.extensions.google.cloud.platform.core.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:111)
        at org.apache.beam.sdks.java.extensions.google.cloud.platform.core.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:58)
        at org.apache.beam.sdks.java.extensions.google.cloud.platform.core.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

If I use this exact same glob with `gsutil` like this `gsutil ls gs://bucket/{file1,file2,file3}` it lists the 3 files correctly. From the code, a glob like this `gs://bucket/dir/*` works.

I use Beam version 2.1.0.

Any idea what's wrong here ?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Beam supports [only a subset of the glob syntax](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/extensions/google-cloud-platform-core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/util/GcsUtil.java#L171) for matching GCS files. It supports `*` and `?`, but not `{}`. Our documentation currently doesn't do a good job of explaining this - it should probably be documented on `FileSystems.match()` and linked from other classes where glob matching is surfaced to users.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, too bad. Do you plan to support `{` or not ? This would be really helpful.

Comment: I'm not aware of anybody in particular working on this, but it of course would be a welcome contribution. With Beam 2.2 (already available at master; release is currently being voted on), if you have multiple separate files to read, consider using FileIO.match()/matchAll()/read(). That will also require an order of magnitude fewer boilerplate than implementing a FileBasedSource.